# readyapi xml get attribute value in groovy

Tags: xml, xml-parsing, attributes, ready-api

I want to get Tag =A  what should i do？

```
def res = '''<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://abc" >
    <Cool Type="abc" >
    </Cool>
    <Cool Type="abg" >
    </Cool>
    <Cool Type="abg" >
    </Cool>
    <Cool Type="abg" >
        <Line LineID="0" Main="1">
            <Info updateDate="17-05-2028" >
                <Selection  Tag="A" Status="Offer"/>
                <Selection  Tag="A" Status="Offer"/>
                <Selection  Tag="A" Status="Offer"/>
            </Info>
        </Line>
    </Cool>
    <Cool Type="abg" >
        <Line LineID="0" Main="1">
            <Info updateDate="17-05-2028" >
                <Selection  Tag="A" Status="Offer"/>
                <Selection  Tag="A" Status="Offer"/>
                <Selection  Tag="A" Status="Offer"/>
            </Info>
        </Line>
    </Cool>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>  '''

xml = new XmlParser().parseText(res)

results = xml.'**'.findAll { it.@Type == 'abg' }

results.each {
    log.info(it.@Type)
}
```

expect output six Tag =A
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c5Vpx.png)

Comment: need Type = “abg”  <=> Tag="A"          I dont know how to write expression

Comment: Your question is very confusing! You are asking about `@Tag` (repeated a lot of times), but your code is referring to `@Type`. Maybe start with the official documentation: [Processing XML](https://groovy-lang.org/processing-xml.html).

Comment: Look up XQuery.